# Anydesk Start Without Login 22.04

Tags: login, 22.04, login-screen, anydesk

I'm using ubuntu 22.04, and I wanted to remote my computer using anydesk. Unfortunately, sometimes when remoting, I need to restart my computer, preventing me from reconnecting to any desk since I need to log in.

Is there any way that I can access any desk without entering the password to the login screen? I also don't want to log in automatically to my computer since it could be risky. Thank you

Answer (score 1):

1. Open terminal
2. Run `sudo nano /etc/systemd/system/anydesk.service`

Should look something like this

```
[Unit]
Description=AnyDesk
Requires=network.target
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
Type=simple
ExecStart=/usr/bin/anydesk --service
PIDFile=/var/run/anydesk.pid
KillMode=mixed
TimeoutStopSec=30
User=root
LimitNOFILE=100000

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

3. Comment out `After=systemd-user-sessions.service`
4. Add `After=syslog.target network-online.target`

(or other events of interest)